# Adding/push to firebase ref with limitToLast?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Firebase states 256 MB for maximum read, so....

Is it possible to push a ref with `limitToLast`?

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();

ref.child("projects").limitToLast(1).push({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: A push isn't a read though, it's a write?

Comment: Ah so `ref.child("projects").limitToLast(1)` does not read first then write. Its as it says just a reference? 

Angularfire confused me.

`var projects = ref.child("projects").limitToLast(1);` 
`var projectsArray = $firebaseArray(projects);`

`projectsArray` now has an array to read?

`projectsArray.$add({ foo: "bar" });`

Comment: Yeah afaik it's just a ref and you don't need limitToLast at all, just the push. If you want to read the list you have to use `.on('value')` or `.once('value')`

Comment: This makes sense and good to get this clear for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

When reading from the database, your query should be limited, filtered or otherwise restricted so that it doesn't hit the 256MB limit, or retrieve excessive amounts of data. When writing to the database, you only need to ensure that the size of a single write request does not exceed 256MB.

Using `firebase.database().ref().child()` generates a [`Reference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference) to a specific location in the database, but doesn't perform any database or network operations. This can then be used to read/write data to/from the database.

Calling `limitToLast()` (or any other filtering methods) on a `Reference` will produce a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query) instead. Similarly, a `Query` does not perform any database or network operations by itself. However, a `Query` can only be instructed to perform **write** operations.

Network operations are only performed when calling specific methods on a `Reference` or `Query`:

- Read operations are performed when calling `on()`, `once()` or variations of these on a `Reference` or `Query`.
- Write operations are performed when calling `set()`, `push()`, `remove()`, `update()` or variations of these on a `Reference` only.

In summary, writing to the database using `push()` won't read data first, so you don't need to worry about hitting the 256MB read limit. Finally, because `limitToLast()` returns a `Query`, you won't then be able to call `push()` on this.